# Breakpoint not working for TableMapper class

Tags: eclipse, debugging, intellij-idea, mapreduce, hbase

I am trying to debug the map function of a hbase mapreducer job in Intellij. The hadoop and hbase environment is setup in my local. We have written a class **TMapper** that extends from **org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapper** and setting that class as the Mapper class in TableMapReduceUtil.

```
static class TMapper extends TableMapper<Text, LongWritable> {

    public TMapper() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void map(ImmutableBytesWritable rowKey, Result columns, Context context) {
        // Mapper code here
        System.out.println("Running Mapper");
    }
}
```

Below is the main function of the jar file

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ApplicationContext context = ConfigHelperService.loadAppContext();
    ConfigHelperService config = context.getBean(ConfigHelperService.class);

    System.out.println("Running Map-Reduce");
    try {
        Configuration hbaseConfig = context.getBean("hbaseConfiguration", Configuration.class);

        Scan scan = PopulateHelper.buildScanner(config.getDeleteProcessedRecords(), 0);
        Job job = Job.getInstance(hbaseConfig, "EntityPopulator");
        int rv = setupAndRunJob(job, scan, config);
        System.exit(rv);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}

private static int setupAndRunJob(Job job, Scan scan, ConfigHelperService config)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {
    
    job.setJarByClass(PopulateTable.class);

    // Configure the Map process to use HBase
    TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(
            HBaseUtils.getQualifiedTableNameString(Consts.TABLE),
            scan,                           // The scan to execute against the table
            TMapper.class,                  // The Mapper class
            Text.class,                     // The Mapper output key class
            LongWritable.class,             // The Mapper output value class
            job);                           // The Hadoop job

    // Configure the reducer process
    job.setReducerClass(TReducer.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(TReducer.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    job.setNumReduceTasks(1);

    String outputPath = config.getOutputPath() + "/" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    log.info("Using output path: " + outputPath);
    Path outputDir = new Path(outputPath);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputDir);

    // Execute the job
    int rv = job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
    log.info("Job Output written to " + outputDir);
    return rv;
}
```

I am executing the below command to run MapReduce job

```
echo hadoop jar ${JARDIR}/my-hbase-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar sa.test.hbase.commands.PopulateTable 2>&1 >> ${LOGFILE} 
    HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$(hbase classpath) HADOOP_OPTS="${HADOOP_OPTS} -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts='-Xmx1792m -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005' -Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=2048 hadoop jar ${JARDIR}/my-hbase-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar sa.test.hbase.commands.PopulateTable 2>&1 >> ${LOGFILE}
```

In intellij, I have created a new remote debug config like below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Il3yO.png)

When I run the hadoop command to run the MapReduce job, it waits for the debugger to start. When I start the debugger from Intellij, it connects to the VM i.e. localhost:5005 and I can see the main function breakpoint is getting hit. But when I put a debug point in the map function of the TMapper class and resume execution, debug point is not getting hit. Although, from the hadoop stdout log, I can see the **Running Mapper** is getting printed and data from a hbase table is processed, copied to another table, and finally deleted.

I followed the same steps using Eclipse and I faced same issue. Breakpoint of Map function in Mapper class is not getting hit. Please advise how I can debug hbase mapreduce job using either Eclipse or Intellij.

I tried to run the jar file with the below command
`java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=5005,server=y,suspend=y -jar my-hbase-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar sa.test.hbase.commands.PopulateTable`

and created remote debugger. I also tried to debug the code as a java application. In both cases, main function breakpoint is working, not Mapper class map function.

Also, I followed the steps written in the below document

https://pravinchavan.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/remote-debugging-of-hadoop-job-with-eclipse/